# Element wise addition of vectors inside a list column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this tibble which has a list column with vectors in them

```
df <- data_frame(grp = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
                 x = rep(c(list(c(1,2,3)), list(c(4,5,6))), 2))
```

What I would like to do (preferably within tidyverse) is to perform element wise addition of the vectors inside the lists,
essentially:

```
c(1,2,3) +  c(4,5,6) 
# [1] 5 7 9
```

This:

```
 # A tibble: 4 × 2
 grp         x
 <chr>    <list>
 A        list(c(1,2,3))
 A        list(c(4,5,6))
 B        list(c(1,2,3))
 B        list(c(4,5,6))
```

Becomes:

```
 # A tibble: 2 × 2
 grp         y
 <chr>    <list>
 A        list(c(5,7,9))
 B        list(c(5,7,9))
```

What might be a good approach?

Comment: Should it be grouped by `grp` ? or every alternate rows?

Comment: Yes, grouped by `grp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should also get you what you need:

```
dff %>% group_by(grp) %>%
        summarise(x = list(Reduce("+",x))) %>%
        ungroup()
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted - very flexible solution too!. Even shorter if you remove the `ungroup` at the end that does nothing :)

Comment: @jenswirf, it's been a force of habit for me to add the `ungroup` every time I use `group`.

Comment: Yes it's best practice to put `%>% ungroup()` at the end, otherwise you return a `tbl_df` which is also a `grouped_df`, which behaves slightly different.

Answer (score 2):

We can try

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
r1 <- lengths(df$x)[1]

unnest(df) %>%
      group_by(grp) %>%
      mutate(grp1 = rep(seq(r1), 2)) %>% 
      group_by(grp1, add = TRUE) %>%
      summarise(x = sum(x)) %>% 
      group_by(grp) %>% 
      summarise(x= list(x))
# A tibble: 2 × 2
#   grp         x
#  <chr>    <list>
#1     A <dbl [3]>
#2     B <dbl [3]>
```